# sql join Query the database ,There is no desired result,

Tags: mysql, sql

my demand is:from database query newest data,according to  time field as a standard,query alarmtime this field ,but  alarmtime < time 
executive sql:

```
SELECT
    c.entryTime AS alarmtime ,
    a.time AS time
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.DB33,
        MAX( t.Time ) AS time,
        t.Stream,
        t.Coil,
        t.`View` 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT DB33, Time, Stream, Coil, `View` 
        FROM running_check 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 1000 ) as t 
    GROUP BY t.DB33 ) AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    select cameraID,cameraName 
    from monitor_link_info) as b ON a.db33 = b.cameraID
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT entryTime, cameraID 
    FROM result_video_v2 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    limit 1000 ) AS c ON a.db33 = c.cameraId 
GROUP BY a.db33, b.cameraName 
ORDER BY a.time DESC, alarmtime DESC
```

execute result is unamiable,please look at image 
now time column not what i want,Because he didn't change.

[image]

Comment: Since you're using `LEFT JOIN`, `alarmtime` can be `NULL`. How should that be handled?

Comment: There's no need for a subquery in the first join, just use `LEFT JOIN monitor_link_info AS b`

Comment: It's not clear why you need to jion with that table at all. You never use `cameraName` in the query except in `GROUP BY`, and it's uniquely determined by `a.db33`.

Comment: Why do you need `GROUP BY` in the main query at all? You're not doing any aggregation there.

Comment: sorry,I didn't make that clear.

Comment: The gentleman upstairs，Your suggestion is very good，but this sql really Faster than you think.

Comment: You should ask another question and provide sample data and desired results *as text tables*.  Provide an explanation of the logic you want as well.  Your query has several weirdnesses, such as unnecessary `LEFT JOIN`s and inconsistent columns in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: yes,I do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    c.entryTime AS alarmtime ,
    a.time AS TIME

    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT DB33, MAX(TIME) TIME, Stream, Coil, `View` 
        FROM running_check 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        GROUP BY t.DB33
        LIMIT 1000 
    ) AS a 

    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT cameraID,cameraName 
        FROM monitor_link_info
        GROUP BY cameraID
        LIMIT 1000
    ) AS b ON (a.db33 = b.cameraID)
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT entryTime, cameraID 
        FROM result_video_v2 
        GROUP BY cameraID
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1000
    ) AS c ON (a.db33 = c.cameraID) 

GROUP BY a.db33, b.cameraName 
ORDER BY a.time DESC, c.entryTime DESC
```

Comment: In my database cannot use your SQL statement

Comment: because execute time fairly long

Comment: Now, try again as above.